# JAX-WS: [java] java.io.IOException: WSDL2Java emitter timed out (this often means the WSDL at the specified URL is inaccessible)

Tags: java, web-services

I have a client service utilizing wsdls and xsd's to talk to a service. Problem is when I try to compile and convert java to wsdl I keep on getting this error: "[java] java.io.IOException: WSDL2Java emitter timed out (this often means the WSDL at the specified URL is inaccessible)"

After some googling I found out that this is a known issue and can be solved by bumping up the time. I am a total novice to this area, can someone help me out on how to increase the time or rather where to increase it?

Thanks!
-Ankush

Answer (score 3):

For axis, you can use the -O or -timeout command line argument to set the timeout, in seconds. Other JAX-WS implementations are similar. Check your WSDL2Java reference.
(e.g., http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/reference.html)